# Error when combining a chain and matrix with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am getting started with TikZ and would like to create complex flow chart. To get used to the package, I want to start simple. However, I already fail at making a simple chain in combination with a matrix.

The code shown in the minial example below throws the error: `no shape named chain-2 is known`. Why is that? Where is my error?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}                       %% Create drawings in LaTeX
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, fill=blue!20, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em, font=\footnotesize]

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[row sep=1mm, column sep=2 mm] {
    % Central row:
        \node (p1)          []      {.};                    &
        \node (stoffVor)    [block] {Stoffvorbereitung};    &
        \node (p2)          []      {.};                    &
        \node (haupt)       [block] {Hauptanlage};          &
        \node (stoffNach)   [block] {Stoffnachbereitung};\\
    };  

    \begin{scope}[start chain]
        \chainin (p1);
        \chainin (stoffvor);
        \chainin (p2);  
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
\begin{scope}[start chain]
    \chainin (p1);
    \chainin (stoffVor);
    \chainin (p2);  
\end{scope}
```

`stoffVor` has lowercase `v` in your example. The code is case sensitive and the error messaging is not always accurately redirecting to the *actual* error (I just wonder why?). If you get an error message, it is a good idea to check also the line before.

Happy `TikZ`-ing! :)

Comment: Don't worry, happens to the best, too ;)